# Joining by 'almost' identical attributes using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, attribute-joins

So I have two point shapefiles - their attribute table consist of names, lat, lon, and others.

I would like to join the attributes of shapefile 1 to shapefile 2. A normal join between the names would to the job.

The problem is that the two datasets have slight differences in the 'name' field as well as in the lat/lon. For example, if I have one point in The Hague, Shapefile 1 will calle it 'Den Hague' whereas Shapefile 2 would calle it 'T. Hague'. Also spatially they are not identical (they do not overlap) so the location between both of them would differ by few kms in spite of being the same point. I have over 7000 points which make it tough for manual corrections. When some points are indeed correct.

Is there a way to do a matching which takes into account ~80% of similarity in the names?

I am using QGIS.

Comment: In SQL, doing a WHERE NAME_A %LIKE% NAME_B usually does a pretty OK job...

Comment: Thanks, but when using this function it says expression invalid?

Comment: what is your expression? can you share a screenshot?

Comment: I would try Levenshtein edit distance.

Comment: It seems I cant paste here a screenshot...
I created a distance matrix for both datasets to see what is the nearest point. In that matrix I put     'WHERE  "GR_name" %LIKE%  "WRI_Name" ' trying to select those fields with a similar name

Comment: @hpnk85 you can edit your question to add additional Informations such as screenshots. How can we understand you "put that expression in that matrix"? Try with a virtual layer.

Comment: Sorry @hpnk85 I usually try not to leave my comment to stand... I got a fluke.... Please see my answer.

Comment: The  syntax should be more like : "GR_name" like '%' || "WRI_Name" || '%'

Comment: I have a problem with fuzzy matching while I generate virtual field (fuzzymatch) all the name of district not included in this field it getting null.

Answer (score 9):

Let me answer to your `Is there a way to do a matching which takes into account ~80% of similarity in the names?`.

QGIS has a function **levenshtein()** which calculates `Levenshtein edit distance`. It is under `Fuzzy matching` group, and you will find detailed description about this function in the help area.

In short, we can quantify how much two input strings are different.

[image]

Above is an example showing the possible usage ---

- `"Led"` (Levenshtein edit distance) field was calculated by `levenshtein('Den Hague', "city")` which is the difference betwen a text `'Den Hague'` and each names in the `"city"` field.
- If `"city"` is `Den Hague`, they are identical. So the `"Led"` returns `0`. And `Rotterdam`, completely different, returns `9`.
- Please note this is case sensitive (see #7).

TLNR;

Above example shows a `"YesNo"` field which determines if two strings match (greater than 80%), by an expression below:

```
CASE WHEN
(length("city") -  levenshtein('Den Hague', "city"))/length('Den Hague') > 0.8
THEN 'Y'
ELSE 'N'
END
```

I am aware your ultimate goal is to use this matching in following `Join` operation. To do that you will need to modify fixed `'Den Hague'` string to a link to your another layer. Please add some more information such as layer name and field names if you need further assistance. Anyway, hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

With QGIS 3.8, now you can use aggregate function to find the closest match to your name using levenshtein distance.

Assuming the target layer is `layer2` and field name is `name`, add a new field fuzzymatch in `layer1` with the following expression and do a join based on that field.

```
array_first(aggregate(
layer:= 'layer2',
aggregate:='array_agg',
expression:=name,
filter:=levenshtein(name, attribute(@parent, 'name')) <= 2,
order_by:=levenshtein(name, attribute(@parent, 'name'))
))
```

I have outlined the steps at https://spatialthoughts.com/2019/09/26/fuzzy-table-joins-in-qgis/